# CSS : Justify dynamically created divs with variable width inside parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am dynamically generating child divs and appending them to parent.Each child div has different width.

```css
  .parent{
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .child{
      margin: 2px;
      float : left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1.2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234245</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23426565</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:25</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23045</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23265</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:45</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:234</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23325545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:232545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:23425</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:25</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle (with **slightly different** markup and CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/tgohguyj/

How can i justify child divs here ?

Comment: For next time, please use a runnable Stack Snippet via the `[<>]` toolbar button. The markup and CSS in the question is **different** than the markup and CSS in the fiddle. I've put your code blocks into a runnable snippet.

Comment: oops wrong fiddle linked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `justify-content:space-between` style on the `parent`

Read more about it here > [justify-content](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-6)

**EDIT :**  you can use `.parent .child:last-child { margin-right:auto }` so if you have only 2 elements on last row, the last element will align next to the previous element

See below

```css
.parent{
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    
}
.parent .child:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.child{
    margin: 2px;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1.2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234245</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23426565</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:25</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23045</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23265</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:45</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:234</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23325545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:232545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:23425</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:235</div>
 
</div>
```

**EDIT 2 :** you can use a pseudo-element to the `.parent` that will behave like a `.child` so it will be a flex-child ( you can add a width to it or not, depending how you would like your last row to look like )

```css
.parent{
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    
}
.parent:after {
  content: '';
  width:50px;
}
.child{
    margin: 2px;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1.2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234245</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23426565</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:25</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23045</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23265</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:45</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:234</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23325545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:232545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:23425</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:235</div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! Perhaps consider adding a border to the child elements to emphasize how their widths are unchanged?

Comment: this works but at last line if there are only two elements then one element goes to left and the other to extreme right....

Comment: @JakeGosemath well that's how `space-between` works. Maybe you can try `space-evenly` instead ? look at that link i gave you in my answer to see the possibilities of `justify-content`

Comment: thanks.. but can't divs be justified like that of simple string.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work for me using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115. It looks the same as flex-start

Comment: @JakeGosemath Edited my answer with a 2 new solutions. check them out

Comment: @MihaiT : awesome..I just have to dynamically adjust the .parent:after width.. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @JakeGosemath glad i could help. Cheers ! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `justify-content:space-between;` for the parent. Remove the float for `.child`. Floats have no effect in a flexbox.

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1.2345</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234235</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234245</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23426565</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:25</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:40px">1345</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23045</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23265</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:45</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:234</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23325545</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:232545</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:23425</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:235</div>
  <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:25</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works but at last line if there are only two elements then one element goes to left and the other to extreme right....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `flex-grow:1` property to child

```css
.parent{
    width:250px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .child{
      margin: 2px;
      float : left;
      flex-grow: 1;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1.2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:234245</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23426565</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:25</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23045</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:23265</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:30px">1:45</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:234</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">1:23325545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:2345</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:232545</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">1:23425</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:50px">1:235</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:40px">1:25</div>
</div>
```

*(Added a border to make the widths of the child elements clearer.)*

Comment: flex-grow changes the width of the `.child` . Their widths ( as i understand ) are dynamic and must stay as given in the inline styles. Also, you deleted those inline styles and also you set all the `.child` with the same content. Why change the op's code ?

Comment: @MihaiT: He/she didn't. The fiddle and the question have *different* content. This answer used the fiddle's content.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder never checked the fiddle :)) sorry.